# Add text to a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google Form with Google Apps Script, I want the Apps script to add text(not a question) but can't see anything within the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app) on how to do this.

Just to clarify [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwx9tvBqDBDXd0Z1LUhTZHZ4dm8/view?usp=sharing) is a screenshot highlighting the function in Google Forms that I would like to access through Apps Script. Hope this makes sense, really appreciate any response.

Thank you,

Connor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example from the docs for creating a TextItem with a title.

```
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var item = form.addTextItem();
 item.setTitle('What is your name?');
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item

EDIT: The SectionHeaderItem Class does what you are looking for. It creates a section header with text but doesn't create a new section.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/section-header-item

```
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var item = form.addSectionHeaderItem();
  item.setTitle('Title of new section');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this adds a question where the user enters a short text answer, I want text that is not a question.

Comment: No problem. I edited my answer to add what you were looking for.